# How can I have a Firestore onSnapshot listener only send changes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am building an application in which my users can message each other. When a user opens a thread, all messages should be loaded. They are then subscribed to the messages of that thread so they also receive updates. I would like Firestore to only send the new messages (rather than the entire thread content) for every added message.
To do this, I subscribe my users with a query for messages added after the current time:

```
let messageData = firebase.firestore().collection('/messages/');

messageData.where('time', '>' , new Date() ).onSnapshot(
      docSnapshot => {
        docSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          ///
        });
      }
);
```

However, as you can imagine, this is only a partial solution as this will always resend all messages after that specific date for every added message.
I could unsubscribe my users after each received message and then re-subscribe them with an updated time, but I feel like that's not really the way it's supposed to happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I feel like that's not really the way it's supposed to happen."* What's wrong, then? If you only want messages after a certain date, then specifying the date as a filter is necessary.

Comment: If a message is sent between an unsubscribe and a subscribe call, then this would be missed by the user. It's also not a very nice solution as this would mean 3 calls (receive new message, unsubscribe, re-subscribe) rather than just the one (receive new message).

Comment: Then you should remember the timestamp of the most recent message received, and only request from that point on.

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought of that, thanks so much!